# Home Folder Android via python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How can I list the folders in my Android Home directory using Python/Kivy? If I run the attached code on my Linux machine, it prints the correct home-folder and all its sub-directories. If I run the same code on my Android-smartphone, it finds the correct home-folder (/storage), but does not list any sub-folders (len = 0). Why doesn't it detect the folders on my smartphone?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        DATA_FOLDER = os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE') or os.path.expanduser("~")
        dir_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(DATA_FOLDER)]
        print(dir_list)
        print(DATA_FOLDER)
        self.add_widget(Button(text = str(len(dir_list))))

class BoxLayoutDemo(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BoxLayoutDemo().run()
```

Comment: The correct way to get the external storage directory on android is to query the android api using pyjnius. There's a function `getExternalStorageDir()`, or something like that, somewhere in the android api. Also, the external storage directory isn't really quite the same as the traditional desktop home directory, although it is probably the closest equivalent.

Comment: There is also an `App` property named `user_data_dir` that is defined for  many platforms (including `Android`).  That directory is intended as where `the user can store data such as preferences, saved games and settings`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir).